# How to find the total of second column using awk commands?

Tags: awk

> Input file(filename:cat)

```
item1,200
item2,499
item3,699
item4,800
```

> Awk command which i had tried

```
awk -F"," '{x+=$2}END{print x}'cat
```

> Error

The above command display empty output.Is it any possible way to overcome with any solutions for it.

Comment: There should be a space between script and filename.

Comment: yeah its working now..@RuudHelderman

Comment: Don't name a file `cat` or any other shell command name.

Answer (score 0):

> Edited and Final command

```
awk -F"," '{x+=$2}END{print x}' cat
```